# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, api, typeerror, react-component, canvasjs

I'm trying to add a canvasjs chart component into another component called dashboard. Sometimes, the data is getting loaded and working fine, sometimes the data is not getting loaded and an error is thrown.

The error goes like this and it points to the doughnutchart.js page and not to dashboard.js page: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
47 | indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
  48 | dataPoints: [
  49 |   {
> 50 |     name: this.props.data.labels[0],
     | ^  51 |     y: this.props.data.datasets[0].data[0],
  52 |   },
  53 |   {
```

DoughnutChart.js :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CanvasJSReact from "../../../assets/canvasjs.react";
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

class DoughnutChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.data);
    window.alert(JSON.stringify(this.props.data));
    this.state = {
      options: {},
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps", nextProps);
    //console.log(this.props.data);
    // if (this.props !== nextProps) {
    //   this.setState(nextProps);
    // }
    //console.log(nextProps.data.labels[0]);
    console.log(this.props.data);

    let options = {
      animationEnabled: true,
      theme: "light2",
      // title: {
      //   text: "Customer Satisfaction",
      // },
      subtitles: [
        {
          // text: "71% Positive",
          // verticalAlign: "center",
          fontSize: 24,
          dockInsidePlotArea: true,
        },
      ],
      data: [
        {
          type: "doughnut",
          radius: "90%",
          innerRadius: "50%",
          showInLegend: true,
          indexLabel: "{y}%",
          //yValueFormatString: "#,###'%'",
          toolTipContent: "{name}: <strong>{y}%</strong>",
          indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
          dataPoints: [
            {
              name: this.props.data.labels[0],
              y: this.props.data.datasets[0].data[0],
            },
            {
              name: this.props.data.labels[1],
              y: this.props.data.datasets[0].data[1],
            },
            {
              name: this.props.data.labels[2],
              y: this.props.data.datasets[0].data[2],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };

    this.setState({
      options,
    });
  }

  render() {
    //let options = {};

    return (
      <div>
        <CanvasJSChart
          options={this.state.options}
          /* onRef={ref => this.chart = ref} */
        />
        {/*You can get reference to the chart instance as shown above using onRef. This allows you to access all chart properties and methods*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DoughnutChart;
```

Comment: It will be better posting this.props.data so that the exact problem can be understood

Comment: console.log(this.props.data) gives me this output in the console                                               Object
datasets: Array(1)
0: {data: Array(3), backgroundColor: Array(3), hoverBackgroundColor: Array(3)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
labels: Array(3)
0: "Bikes"
1: "Cars"
2: "Buses"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: This is not the way, convert to string and post. console.log(JSON.stringity(this.props.data))

Comment: I'm getting this error :                                                                                                           
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
DoughnutChart.componentWillReceiveProps
DoughnutChart.js:51
  48 | indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
  49 | dataPoints: [
  50 |   {
> 51 |     name: this.props.data.labels[0],
     | ^  52 |     y: this.props.data.datasets[0].data[0],
  53 |   },
  54 |   {
View compiled